# PTIJ: Is the genie's lamp considered Metaltilin (movable objects) or Karka (land)?

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

The [genie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genie_(Disney)) (from Aladdin) lives in a lamp. Assuming the lamp has living quarters, does one need a Chazakah of living there for 3 years to own the lamp (or require a document of sale), or is it Metaltilin, and by merely possessing it, others have the burden of proof to counter it (Hamotzei M'Chavero Alav HaRayah)?

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Comment: Presumably it would be metaltelin, same as a ship (which, for example, is acquired with mesirah, not like land with kesef or shtar, etc.).

Answer (score 1):

It is part of the binding of a genie that they must serve the owner of the lamp (or a comparable object such as a djinn's ring).  Since this ownership can be established by claiming possession of a long-abandoned object, Genie's lamp counts as *metaltilin* and falls under the *chazakah* of movable property.

The interior of the lamp (or other object) constitutes a residence, just like condominium ownership gives title to the interior of the unit but not the exterior structure or land.  The interior falls under the *chazakah* of real estate.

However, please CYLOR and estate lawyer before starting any effort to establish ownership by adverse possession of such an iiiiiiity-bitty living space claimed by a being of incredible cosmic power.  (*That* Genie can't kill you, but you'd be astonished what you can live through.  Proper general and medical powers of attorney are strongly indicated.)